# Phonegap android - window.plugins undefined

Tags: phonegap-plugins

I have created my own Plugin, which calls a class written in java. I want to call this plugin from Javascript code. The error comes in the code:

```
window.plugins.locationListing.list("/sdcard",
        function(r){gotLocation(r)},
        function(e){onError(e)}
);
```

window.plugins is undefined.

Following are the things I have done:
1) Created a LocationFinder plugin class in my source folder
2) Added the plugin to res/xml/plugins.xml

```
<plugin name="LocationFinder" value="com.phonegap.plugins.locationListing.LocationFinder"/>
```

3) Created a javascript file called locationlisting.js:

```
var LocationListing = function() {
};

LocationListing.prototype.list = function(directory, successCallback, failureCallback) {
  return PhoneGap.exec(successCallback,    
      failureCallback,
      'LocationFinder',
      'list',
      directory);
};
```

4) In my main.html added locationlisting.js, main.js, phonegap-1.0.0.js.
5) From my main.js, I call the plugin, that is where I execute the first piece of code I wrote above, copied below:

```
function callPlugin() {
    window.plugins.locationListing.list("/sdcard",
        function(r){gotLocation(r)},
        function(e){onError(e)}
    );
}
```

This is where window.plugins is undefined. What could be the problem? I have all my js files stored in www/. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For point 2) where I add the plugin to plugins.xml, what should the value="" string be? Is it okay as the way I have written it?

Also, does the Plugin class LocationFinder be in the src directory, or in some other directory.

Comment: `value` should be the full package name of the class. `LocationFinder.java` should be under `com.phonegap.plugins.locationListing` package as you have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the registration part, in your locationlisting.js file:

```
PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("locationListing", new LocationListing());
});
```

You can refer couple of sample plugins templates I have created [here](https://github.com/dhavaln/phonegap-plugins)